# sending data to specific IP and port

Tags: c#

How can I send data to a specific port and ip?
I need to send the following data:

```
0000000122&ServiceID=1&QueryCode=code1
```

to 192.168.1.1:9184 (there is a program that listens on this port)

Do I need to use TcpClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look a link.You get nice example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx